# Serializing Hashset contents to a SQL table

Tags: sql, serialization, openxml, hashset

I have a hashset that I want to serialize to a SQL Server table.  When serialized hashset looks like this...

```
<InstallerContactIds>
   <int>153771</int> 
   <int>209572</int> 
</InstallerContactIds>
```

I am using the following to insert the XML into the table...

```
INSERT INTO dbo.cv_AssessorActionPlanInstallers
SELECT @AssessorActionPlanId, InstallerId
From OPENXML (@XmlDocumentHandle, 'AssessorActionPlan/InstallerContactIds', 2) 
With
(
    InstallerId int 'int'           
)
```

However, I only get the first id inserted into the table.  Is it possible to insert all ids in this case?

I am using SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what version of SQL you are using, but if you are on 2005 or newer, you can use the new [XML data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189887.aspx).

```
declare @xml xml
select @xml = '
<InstallerContactIds>
   <int>153771</int> 
   <int>209572</int> 
</InstallerContactIds>'

select
    x.i.value('.', 'int')
from
    @xml.nodes('/InstallerContactIds/int') as x(i)
```

If you are stuck using OpenXML, it should work if you do this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.cv_AssessorActionPlanInstallers
SELECT @AssessorActionPlanId, InstallerId
From OPENXML (@XmlDocumentHandle, 'AssessorActionPlan/InstallerContactIds/int', 2) 
With
(
    InstallerId int '.'
)
```

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for replying.  The OPENXML method concatenates the ids together and attempts to insert them (but fails due to int overflow).  I will investigate the XML data type as I am using 2005

Comment: Col, if your numbers are overflowing int, you can try using the bigint datatype.  I executed the query using the sample XML you posted (modifying the OPENXML statement to remove the 'AssessorActionPlan' since that wasn't in your example XML) and it returned both numbers fine.